# How to render by Vue instead of Jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, vue.js, jinja2

```
<template id="task-template">
    <h1>My Tasks</h1>
    <tasks-app></tasks-app>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="task in list">
            {{task.body|e}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

This above is my html.  I want to render the code by Vue instead.

```
<script>
    Vue.component('tasks-app', {
        template: '#tasks-template',
        data: function() {
            return {
                list: []
            }
        }
        created: function() {
            $.getJson('/api/tasks', function(data) {
                this.list = data;
            })
        }
    })
    new Vue({
        el: 'body',
    });
</script>
```

The above is my Vue code, and Jinja raise an exception that 'task' is undefined, what I hope for is that the html code rendered by Vue instead of Jinja, I know it could be done in Laravel with this:

```
"@{{task.body}}"
```

Since I am new to Jinja, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Is you list getting populated properly, can you see the array in HTML and post it in question?

Comment: If you are using Flask you can re-define the delimiter. https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/3925738

Answer (score 89):

The other option is to redefine the delimiters used by Vue.js. This is handy if you have a lot of existing template code and you wish to start adding Vue.js functionality to a Flask or Django project.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  delimiters: ['[[',']]']
})
```

Then in your HTML you can mix your Jinja and Vue.js template tags:

```
    <div id="app">
      {{normaltemplatetag}}
      [[ message ]] 
    </div>
```

Not sure when the ["delimiters"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) property was added, but it is in version 2.0.

Comment: for everybody who is trying to implement vue.js as a front-end on a django-rest backend, this comment is a godsend. it saved me so much frustration and magically misrendered or un-rendered elements.

Comment: @mburke05 It's also possible to redefine the delimiters used by jinja2 - it all depends on which one you document as what.

Comment: This works in some cases, but doesn't seem to work within <template> sections within the HTML. @Mani use of `raw` does the trick, as does changing the Jinja2 delimiters.

Answer (score 44):

You need to define parts of your template as **raw** so that Jinja escapes that portion instead of trying to fill it up with its own context.

Here is how you need to do it:

```
<template id="task-template">
  <h1>My Tasks</h1>
  <tasks-app></tasks-app>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="task in list">
        {% raw %}{{task.body|e}}{% endraw %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Ref: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping

Comment: you can also use a shorthand to {% raw %}. This is done as {{ '{{task.body|e}}' }}

Answer (score 16):

If you're using Flask, you can redefine the delimiters used by Jinja:

```
class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        variable_start_string='%%',  # Default is '{{', I'm changing this because Vue.js uses '{{' / '}}'
        variable_end_string='%%',
    ))


app = CustomFlask(__name__)  # This replaces your existing "app = Flask(__name__)"
```

Answer (score 14):

You can either change default VueJS or Jinja delimiters. I actually prefer to change VueJS delimiters like below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

Then you can use `${variable}` instead of conflicting `{{ var }}`, see [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters).

This matches with ES6 template string style, so it is preferable I would say. Keep in mind that you will have to do same when you crate new components.

Alternatively, you could just bypass Jinja template rendering altogether. Just move your `index.html` from templates directory to static directory (next to css, js files), then:

```py
@app.route("/")
def start():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

If you are doing all view logic in VueJS, this can work.

Answer (score 5):

Use `{{ '{{ vue }}' }}`

I had the same problem, and also got it solved.

Answer (score 4):

Configure Vue v2 class instance with the 'delimiters' option:

```
<div id='myapp'> !{ message } </div>
<script>
let myapp = new Vue({ delimiters: ['!{', '}'], ...});
</script>
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Answer (score 2):

You can use **directives**

```
<h3 v-text="message"></h3>
```

Or you can use **delimiters**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    data: {
    message: 'a vue message'
    },
});
```

In your **html page**

```
<h3>${ message }</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use {% raw %} {% endraw %} in your html code

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post, and however @Nathan Wailes answer helped me. I further tried avoiding moustaches `{{myVal}}` and used `v-text="myVar"` for rendering text. And I did not need to override jinja delimiters. see example below:

```
<!--Vuetify-->    
<v-btn class="ma-2" outlined color="indigo" v-text="connectToggleLabel"></v-btn>
<v-btn class="ma-2" outlined color="indigo"><span v-text="connectToggleLabel"/></v-btn>
<!-- basic -->
<input type="button" :value="connectToggleLabel"/>
```

Hope this help somebody