# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'asset' is undefined

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask

I am fetching API data through my Python backend which I then render through Flask to my Vue.js frontend. However, I am getting the error in the title.

I have checked and printed the variable I am trying to pass, and it prints the content of the list fine.

This is how I render the variable from Python:

```
def index():
    # Get the assets data
    assets = get_assets()
    
    # Return the template with the assets data
    return render_template("index.html", asset_data=assets)
```

And this is how I have it setup in my HTML file. First I run through the list using v-for:

```
                <tr v-for="asset in assets">
                    <td>{{ asset.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ asset.symbol }}</td>
                </tr>
```

And I have this JS script:

```
        <script>
            const app = new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                data: {
                assets: {{ asset_data }}
                }
            });
        </script>
```

My list looks like this:

```
                    {
                        "name": "Asset 1",
                        "symbol": "A1",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Asset 2",
                        "symbol": "A2",

                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Asset 3",
                        "symbol": "A2",

                    } ......
```

Could someone please help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `asset_data` list is valid JSON, [you most likely need to redefine the delimiters used in Vue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082626/how-to-render-by-vue-instead-of-jinja)

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        assets: {{ asset_data }},
    },
    delimiters: ['[[',']]']
});
```

And then in your Vue HTML, you can use this `[[ ]]` delimiter:

```html
<tr v-for="asset in assets">
    <td>[[ asset.name ]]</td>
    <td>[[ asset.symbol ]]</td>
</tr>
```

As you know, Jinja and Vue use the same double curly brace delimiter by default (`{{ }}`), and as a consequence, Jinja was interpreting your Vue variable (`{{ asset.name }}`) as a Jinja variable.

Another alternative without redefining the Vue delimiters, is to just wrap the [Jinja `{% raw %}` tag](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#escaping) around your Vue variables:

```html
<tr v-for="asset in assets">
    <td>{% raw %}{{ asset.name }}{% endraw %}</td>
    <td>{% raw %}{{ asset.symbol }}{% endraw %}</td>
</tr>
```

This tells Jinja to ignore parts of your template.

Hope this helps.